Can the Xero API return custom reports?
I'm using the API explorer and would like to pull the Account Transactions standard report with 2 extra columns selected, so I save this as a custom report Account Transactions Custom, but it is always a 404 for both standard and non-standard?
GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/AccountTransactions = 404
GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports/AccountTransactionsCustom = 404
enter image description here
When I run GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Reports there are no reports found.
How can I pull the Account Transactions standard or custom report using the API?
I'm expecting the API to allow me to pull a standard or custom report by name/ID.

It is not possible to retrieve custom reports through the API.
Also Xero doesn't currently have the Account Transactions report available via the API at this stage. However, if you're looking to build an app that creates reports from information out of Xero for you, the Journals endpoint on the API may help.
Every transaction created in Xero that effects the general ledger creates an accounting journal in the background. Typically you can only see these journals in the Journal report found in the Report Centre, however they are also available via the API.
If you pull all the journals from your organisation you'll be able to build your own reports as required. To do this you would need to perform an initial process to retrieve the complete set of journals. If these were then stored locally it would only need to be a one-time process. Subsequent updates would only need to retrieve any new journals.
